# Can there be an active input to the pi's GPIO before i/o set-up?

Tags: gpio

I'm wondering if a 3.3v input to the Pi's GPIO before it is set up will damage that pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest connecting 3.3V to any MOS device before it is powered up is a bad idea, as it risks reverse biassing the substrate. At the least you should use a series resistor to limit current.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly legal to attach a input to the gpio before it is "setup". Although when plugging in wires it is a good idea to turn off your raspberry pi.

I suggest reading the gpio [docs](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/). Here is a [pinout](http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/3040/raspberrypirev2pinout.jpg) diagram of the gpio.